# How to Reset the value for the enum radio button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, enums, reset

I have written a script function to reset the controls of my page using jquery. I got an enum like this

```
 public enum enumCurrencyType
 {
    [Description("Home Currency")]
    HomeCurrency=1,

    [Description("Foreign Currency")]
    ForeignCurrency = 2,
 }
```

And my cshtml page,

```
   <div class="col-md-4 fnt-sz-1">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    <b>Currency Type <font color="red">*</font></b></label><br />
                <div class="radio col-md-4">
                    @Html.EnumRadioButtonFor(m => m.enumCurrencyType, false).DisableIf(() =>     
   Model.IsReadOnly == true)
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my reset button and function is following

```
<input id="clickMe" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Reset" 
    onclick="clearInput();" />

function clearInput(){
  //Clear Text Box value
  $('form input, form select').each(function(index) {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.attr('type') == 'text') {
      input.val('');
    }
    $("#enumCurrencyType").val(1);
  });
}
```

Here I don't know how to reset the enumCurrencyType control, So please Can anybody please help to find the solution

Comment: Why would you loop over selects to see if their types are text? Also you set the enumCurrencyType (of which there should be only one since you must have unique ID) to one in every single instance of other fields

Comment: What is `EnumRadioButtonFor()`. Is your own extension method? What html does it render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#enumCurrencyType").val(1);
```

Try

```
$("#enumCurrencyType[value='1']").prop('checked',true);
```

OR

```
$("#enumCurrencyType[value='1']").attr('checked','checked');
```

**EDIT :-**

As the **id** in HTML generated by `EnumRadioButtonFor()` is `_enumCurrencyType_HomeCurrency`,So try this :-

```
$("#_enumCurrencyType_HomeCurrency[value='1']").prop('checked',true);
```

OR

```
$("#_enumCurrencyType_HomeCurrency[value='1']").attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: I want to check 'HomeCurrency' radio button when click the reset button, so please help me

Comment: @ Kartikeya..I tried it in lots of ways, but not working

Comment: @MdAslam...check the html generated by `EnumRadioButtonFor()`

Comment: @ Kartikeya...Ya its working. Here the problem is , the Id is not "enumCurrencyType " it's "_enumCurrencyType_HomeCurrency".I have seen it from Original Source in IE8(Right click -->ViewSource)

Comment: @MdAslam..yes..that is why i was asking you to check html generated by `EnumRadioButtonFor()` .. anyways..happy helping you :)